# Get notification using AlarmManager setRepeating after every minute

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to create a app in which the user is notified after every hour. To make this I user AlarmManager and used setRepeating() to repeat the alarm and in that I gave Intent in which I have registered the broadcast receiver.

This works fine. I get notification every hour.

The alarm is set on button click event.

But, as soon as I clear my app from the recent activity list I don't get the notification. Again I opened the app and recreated the alarm at that time it gives me the notification.

What should I do to get the notification even if my app is closed. And even if there is no activity running of my app in background.

Is it possible to get using AlarmManager.

Here is my code:

Activity class:

```
package com.example.positionexample;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button bt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();   
                //startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pendingIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Broadcast receiver class:

```
package com.example.positionexample;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        generateNotification( context,  intent);
        Log.e("","Don't panik but your time is up!!!!.");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Don't panik but your time is up!!!!.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void generateNotification(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "New E-mail", System.currentTimeMillis());

        PendingIntent bintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        note.setLatestEventInfo(context, "New E-mail", "You have one unread message.", bintent);

        notifManager.notify(123, note);
    }

}
```

Manfest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.positionexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!-- <service 
            android:enabled="true" 
            android:name="com.example.positionexample.MyService" 

            /> -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.positionexample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you found the solution on your problem? I also have the same problem. It only notifies when i open my application.

Answer (score 0):

> But, as soon as I clear my app from the recent activity list I don't get the notification

That should only occur on devices where the manufacturer tied swiping off the recent-tasks to do what normally only happens when the user presses "Force Stop" for your app in Settings. Among other things, "Force Stop" removes your scheduled alarm events.

You can use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see whether your alarms are still scheduled.

> What should I do to get the notification even if my app is closed

If the user force-stops your app, your app will never run again, until the user manually launches one of your activities.

Normally, swiping off the recent-tasks list will merely stop your current process, leaving your alarms alone.

Dave Smith has [a good blog post](http://www.doubleencore.com/2014/06/effects-android-application-termination/) up about the effects of different ways of "closing" your app.